# Python: how to get a difference between all elements of the list with orignal indices saved

Tags: python, sorting

So lets suppose we have a list :

```
x = [0.2 , 0.1 , 0.3 , 0.100000001 , 0.200000002]
```

what I dont want to allow is difference between all the elements less than 1e-05 to be flagged as a `True` in the resulting list
One way of doing would be to sort it first

```
   y =  x.sort()

   z= abs(np.diff(y))

  result = [False] + [i< 1e-5 for i in (z)]
```

so the resulting list is something like

```
[False True False True False]
```

but this way I lose the orignal positions in the resulting list, what I would want is a listwhich results in such a manner

```
[True True False True True]
```

Comment: Could you please rephrase the sentence *"what I dont want to allow is difference between all the elements less than 1e-05 to be flagged as a True in the resulting list"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do something like:

```
>>> [any(abs(y - z) < 1e-5 for z in x if z != y) for y in x]
[True, True, False, True, True]
>>>
```

Comment: I think this differs from what the OP wants, in several regards. (1) You should probably use `abs` when comparing. (2) I think the OP wants to return `True` at position `i` if there is at least another number in the list that differs from `x[i]` by less than 1e5, even if that other number is not adjacent.

Comment: @Stef Got the OP's logic, edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I do not guarantee that I interpreted the question correctly.*

**Short and simple, but quadratic in complexity:**

```py
x     = [0.2 , 0.1 , 0.3 , 0.100000001 , 0.200000002]
final = [any(abs(a-b)<1e-05 for b in x) for a in x]
```

**n log(n) complexity using sorting:**

If you want to remember the original positions of the elements, then store these positions explicitly in the list, using builtin function [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

```py
x     = [0.2 , 0.1 , 0.3 , 0.100000001 , 0.200000002]
y     = sorted(enumerate(x), key=lambda pair: pair[1])
z1    = [abs(a[1]-b[1]) < 1e-05 for a,b in zip(y, y[1:])]
z     = [(i[0],(b1 or b2)) for (i,b1,b2) in zip(y, z1 + [False], [False] + z1)]
final = [b for i,b in sorted(z)]

>>> x
[0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.100000001, 0.200000002]
>>> y
[(1, 0.1), (3, 0.100000001), (0, 0.2), (4, 0.200000002), (2, 0.3)]
>>> z1 + [False]  # comparing with next element
[True, False, True, False, False]
>>> [False] + z1  # comparing with previous element
[False, True, False, True, False]
>>> z
[(1, True), (3, True), (0, True), (4, True), (2, False)]
>>> final
[True, True, False, True, True]
```